# Flutter visibility buttons 1 visible at a time problem

Tags: flutter

so ive been trying to get my buttons to make visible an other widget one at a time(aka when a second widget goes to true on the visibility var the first to go false) using the Visibility widget and cannot make it work.Am new too so i could really use some help.

The first three widgets are the buttons and the other three Widgets are the pop ups i want each one associated with each button.
My code:

```
Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          height: 60.0,
                          width: 60.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          child: Icon(_filtericons[0],
                              size: 25.0,
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 7,
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          height: 60.0,
                          width: 60.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          child: Icon(_filtericons[1],
                              size: 25.0,
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 7,
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          height: 60.0,
                          width: 60.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          child: Icon(_filtericons[2],
                              size: 25.0,
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ]),
              )),
          Visibility(
              visible: false,
              child: Container(
                height: 270.0,
                width: 320.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              )),
          Visibility(
              visible: false,
              child: Container(
                height: 270.0,
                width: 320.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              )),
          Visibility(
              visible: true,
              child: Container(
                height: 270.0,
                width: 320.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              )),
```

Answer (score 0):

make a list of bools

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

   @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
   }

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 List<bool> list=[false,false,false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
   
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
   
    child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          list[0]=true;
                          list[1]=false;
                          list[2]=false;
                          
                        });

                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      width: 60.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(Icons.filter,
                          size: 25.0,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 7,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                         setState(() {
                          list[0]=false;
                          list[1]=true;
                          list[2]=false;
                          
                        });


                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      width: 60.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(Icons.filter,
                          size: 25.0,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 7,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {

                         setState(() {
                          list[0]=false;
                          list[1]=false;
                          list[2]=true;
                          
                        });

                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      width: 60.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(Icons.filter,
                          size: 25.0,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    )),
    
               
          
      Visibility(
          visible: list[0],
          child: Container(
            height: 270.0,
            width: 320.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
          )
          ),
      Visibility(
          visible: list[1],
          child: Container(
            height: 270.0,
            width: 320.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
          )
          ),
      Visibility(
          visible: list[2],
          child: Container(
            height: 270.0,
            width: 320.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
          )), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
  ] )));
 }
 }
```

Comment: I did exactly that and still can't get my container showing.I don't have any errors either and its kinda weird